# Display of an editable color input field in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

As you can see in the code below, i have a grid with editable cells. At the column named "szin" i tired to implement a kendo colorpicker and it works just fine.
My problem is, that the colors are only displayed when you try to edit one of the cell. Can i make it permanently displayed somehow? I dont care if the bg-color of the cell change or the dropdown box visible all the time or with any other methods.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../styles/kendo.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid" style="width:1024px; height:400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: "load.php",
                        update: {
                            url: "load.php",
                            type: "POST"

                        }/*,
                        destroy: {
                            url: "load.php",
                            type: "DELETE"
                        }*/

                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        alert(e.responseText);
                    }
                },
                columns: [  { field: "termekid", width:"70px" },
                            /*
                            ...
                            */
                            { field: "szin", width:"74px",
                                editor: szinColorPickerEditor
                            }
                            /*
                            ...
                            */

                        ],
                sortable: true,
                editable: true,
                navigatable: true,
                toolbar: ["save", "cancel"/*, "create"*/],
                pageable: {
                        previousNext: true,
                        numeric: true,
                        buttonCount: 5,
                        input: false,
                        pageSizes: [0, 10, 20, 50, 100],
                        refresh: true,
                        info: true


                    }

            });

            function szinColorPickerEditor(container, options) {
                $("<input type='color' data-bind='value:" + options.field + "' />")
                    .appendTo(container)
                    .kendoColorPicker({
                        buttons: true

                    });

            }


        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a column template for this, for example you could change your field definition to:

```
{
    field: "szin",
    width: "74px",
    editor: szinColorPickerEditor,
    template: "<span style='display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #= szin #'></span>"
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/JEnSs/)