# Kendo UI Grid cell background color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In kendo ui grid how can i change the background color? I've tried to set the template for the column but when the grid is visualized, it's empty without any color.
I have this code:

```
$scope.thingsOptions = {
    sortable: "true",
    scrollable: "true",
    columns: [
              { field: "Colore", title: "Colore", width: "160px", template: "<div><span style='background-color:red'></span></div>" }
             ]

};
```

How can i apply a template to color the background of the cell

Comment: a span is an inline element, so without content, it'll have 0 width; take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20287263/2001735

Answer (score 8):

how to add conditional cell background?

what it does is: it builds a text row template from all parameters if there is no row template given.
it is possible to add template text in most of the parameters like:

```
...
//},
    columns : [  
            {
                title : 'Questions Translated',
                attributes:{ 'style':"#=questions!==questionsMax?'background-color: red; color:white;':''#" },
                field : "questions",
                width: 140
            },

...
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is essentially fine. You can do it as you are doing *but* the you are not seeing it because the `span` and the `div` are empty so the element has `0px` width and you cannot see it.

Try doing:

```
$scope.thingsOptions = {
    sortable: "true",
    scrollable: "true",
    columns: [
        { 
            field: "Colore", 
            title: "Colore", 
            width: "160px", 
            template: "<div><span style='background-color:red'>This is a test</span></div>" 
        }
    ]
};
```

or

```
$scope.thingsOptions = {
    sortable: "true",
    scrollable: "true",
    columns: [
        { 
            field: "Colore", 
            title: "Colore", 
            width: "160px", 
            template: "<div style='background-color:red'>&nbsp;</div>"
        }
    ]
};
```

or even:

```
$scope.thingsOptions = {
    sortable: "true",
    scrollable: "true",
    columns: [
        { 
            field: "Colore", 
            title: "Colore", 
            width: "160px", 
            template: "<span style='float: left; width: 100%; background-color:red'>&nbsp;</div>"
        }
    ]
};
```

It is important to note that the content of the `span` and/or `div` are not empty: they contain a `&nbsp;`.

**BUT** if you want it colored and no padding / margin, then you can use:

```
{ 
    field: "Colore", 
    title: "Colore", 
    width: "160px", 
    attributes: {
        style: "background-color: red"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is possibe to use attributes with conditions? Using div in template is causing unwanted padding but i would like to colorize whole cell in order of cell value.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to color the whole column, you can add `attributes` property in the column specification.

For example:

```
columns: [
    { 
        field: "Colore", 
        title: "Colore", 
        width: "160px", 
        attributes: {
            "class": "weekend"
        }
    }
]
```

And in your .css file you specify the weekend class as:

```
.weekend{
    background-color: #F7DCAA;
}
```

More info [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.attributes)

Comment: Actually, you don't need to create a weekend class.  With kendo you can use k-weekend:  .k-calendar .k-weekend
{ 
  background: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [footerStyle] and [headerStyle] attributes to change the grid color, for example

```
 <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
        <kendo-grid-column
          field="ContactName"
          title="Contact Name"
          [width]="150"
          [headerStyle]="{'background-color': '#666','color': '#fff','line-height': '1em'}"
          [style]="{'background-color': '#888','color': '#fff'}"
          [footerStyle]="{'background-color': '#888','color': '#fff'}"
        >
          <ng-template kendoGridFooterTemplate>Contacts: 10</ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column
          field="CompanyName"
          title="Company Name"
          [headerStyle]="{'background-color': '#666','color': '#fff','line-height': '1em'}"
        >
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column
          field="City"
          title="City"
          [headerStyle]="{'background-color': '#666','color': '#fff','line-height': '1em'}"
        >
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```