# Kendo ColorPalette not posting value to controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I'm currently trying to get a `kendo ColorPalette` to work with inline editing on my grid. I've pretty much got it all figured out except that I'm having some difficulties posting the selected color value to my controller.

Kendo Grid:

```
$("#ContactTagsGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Admin/Tag/GetTagsByOrg",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    orgId: OrganizationId
                }
            },
            create: {
                url: "/Admin/Tag/Create",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: function () {
                    return kendo.antiForgeryTokens();
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number", nullable: true },
                    OrgId: { type: "number" },
                    Name: { type: "string" },
                    Color: { type: "string", defaultValue: "#f20000", validation: { required: true } }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20
    }),
    pageable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: {
        extra: false
    },
    scrollable: false,
    columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                field: "Name"
            },
            {
                field: "Color",
                editor: colorEditor,
                template: function(dataItem) {
                    return "<div style='width: 25px; background-color: " + dataItem.Color + ";'>&nbsp;</div>";
                },
                width: "500px"
            },
            {
                command: [
                    {
                        name: "Edit",
                        template:
                            "<a href='\\#' class='small btn btn-link k-grid-edit edit-text'><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span>Edit</a>",
                        text: "",
                        className: "fa fa-pencil"
                    },
                    {
                        template:
                            "<a href='\\#' class='small btn btn-link danger delete-text k-grid-delete'><span class='fa fa-trash-o'></span>Delete</a>",
                        name: "Delete",
                        text: " Delete",
                        className: "fa fa-trash-o"
                    }
                ],
                width: "170px"
            }
        ],
        editable: {
            mode: "inline",
            destroy: false // don't use the kendo destroy method since we're using bootbox
        },
        // Custom save/cancel buttons
        edit: function (e) {
            var command = e.container.find("td:last");
            command.html("<a href='\\#' class='small btn btn-primary k-grid-update'>Save</a><a href='\\#' class='small btn btn-default k-grid-cancel' style='margin-left: 5px'>Cancel</a");
        }
});
```

Javascript to replace the default grid inline-editor with the `Kendo ColorPalette`:

```
function colorEditor(container, options) {
    // create an input element
    var div = $("<div></div>");
    var input = $("<input />");

    input.attr("name", "Color");
    // append it to the container
    div.appendTo(container);
    input.appendTo(div);

    // initialize a Kendo UI ColorPicker
    div.kendoColorPalette({
        palette: [
            "#f20000", "#c60000", "#337a00"
        ],
        columns: 3,
        change: function () {
            var color = this.value();
            $("input[name=Color]").val(color);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on the `Save` button, the only values that are posted to my controller are the `Name` and the `OrgId`.

If I set a `defaultValue` in the schema of my model like I did in the code above, then the default value for `Color` is always posted no matter if I select a different color or not.

If I do not set a `defaultValue` in the schema, then the value that is posted for `Color` is `null`.

So basically, I just need help updating my model so that it is correct when posting to the controller. I can see that the value of my input `<input name="Color" />` is being updated correctly every time that I select a new color but again, it's not actually posting the value that it contains.

Not sure if this is needed, but here is what my model looks like:

```
public class TagCreateViewModel
{
    public int OrgId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are avoiding the Kendo Color Picker? Also, the grid posts the data item to the controller, not the controls in the row. You will need to data bind the row data item to the input in order to get it to post.

Comment: @Failwyn I prefer the look of the Color Palette rather than the Color Picker so that's why I'm using it. But yeah, I did a little more research and stumbled across a different answer that helped solve my problem. You are correct though in that I need to be binding the row data to the input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up stumbling across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286273/kendo-ui-editable-color-input-field-on-grid) question on SO that helped me solve my problem. I just adapted it to use the `Kendo Color Palette` instead and it works perfectly now.

```
function colorEditor(container, options) {
    $("<div type='color' data-bind='value:" + options.field + "'/>")
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoColorPalette({
            palette: [
                "#f20000", "#c60000", "#337a00", "#54b010", "#9adc0d", "#28cb9b", "#0eac98", "#0ed6e8", "#14a7d1",
                "#bc0aef", "#560ea7", "#2713bc", "#1457d1"
            ],
            columns: 7
        });
}
```